# Node.js server sends back EOF block the PHP server

Tags: php, node.js, apache, sockets, proxy

I have a node.js server opening 8000 port. It is a chat server.
I have another PHP server and I use proxy + virtual host so when I go www.phpserver.com/chat It proxies to the node.js server. I did this so I can use ajax to call the node.js server.

Right now, everything works fine when i run the node.js server, however, after a while (a random time frame, not necessarily long or short), the PHP server will crush because it gets an EOF from the node.js server and it's just stuck there until I stop/restart the node.js server.

The error I get is(from php error log):

> (70014)End of file found: proxy: error reading status line from remote
>   server nodeserver.com:8000, referer: https://www.phpserver.com

I asked some professionals and they said it's because of the PHP server sends the request to the node.js server successfully and receives an EOF or fails to receive any response. I don't understand how to fix it tho. What should I do so even the node.js server crushes, it won't crush the PHP server? Should I get rid of the proxy+ajax and starts to use socket.io?

Please advise.

Thank you!

---

Below is some node codes.

From middleware:

```
       this.events.addListener('update', o_.bind(function(package) {
    if(this.clear != 0){
    delete this.sessions[this.clear];
    }
        var _package = package.toJSON();
        if(package.type == 'status' && package.status == 'offline') {
            var sids = Object.keys(this.sessions), sid, sess;
            for(sid in this.sessions) {
                sess = this.sessions[sid];
                if(sess.data('username') == package.username) {
                    if(sess.listeners.length)
                        sess.send(200, {type: 'goodbye'});
                    delete this.sessions[sid];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }, this));
};

Hub.prototype.destroy = function(sid, fn) {
    this.set(sid, null, fn);
};

Hub.prototype.reap = function(ms) {
    var threshold = +new Date - ms,
        sids = Object.keys(this.sessions);
    for(var i = 0, len = sids.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var sid = sids[i], sess = this.sessions[sid];
        if(sess.lastAccess < threshold) {
         this.events.emit('update', new packages.Offline(sess.data('username')));
        }
    }
};


Hub.prototype.get = function(req, fn) {
    if(this.sessions[req.sessionID]) {
        fn(null, this.sessions[req.sessionID]);
    } else {
        this.auth.authenticate(req, o_.bind(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                var session = new User(req.sessionID, data);
                this.set(req.sessionID, session);

                this.auth.friends(req, data, o_.bind(function(friends) {
                    var friends_copy = friends.slice();
                    o_.values(this.sessions).filter(function(friend) {
                        return ~friends.indexOf(friend.data('username'));
                    }).forEach(function(friend) {
                        var username = friend.data('username');
                        friends_copy[friends_copy.indexOf(username)] =
                                            [username, friend.status()];
                    }, this);

                    session._friends(friends_copy);
            console.log("refreshed");
                    session.events.addListener('status',
                        o_.bind(function(value, message) {
                            this.events.emit(
                                'update',
                                new packages.Status(session.data('username'),
                                                    value,
                                                    message)
                            );
                        }, this));
                    this.events.addListener('update',
                                      o_.bind(session.receivedUpdate, session));
                    this.set(req.sessionID, session);
                    fn(null, session);
                }, this));
            } else {
                fn();
            }
        }, this));
    }
};
```

From app.js

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node
var sys = require('sys'),
    express = require('express'),
    packages = require('./libs/packages'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    o_ = require('./libs/utils'),
    https = require('https');

o_.merge(global, require('./settings'));
try { o_.merge(global, require('./settings.local')); } catch(e) {}

try {
    var daemon = require('./libs/daemon/daemon'),
        start = function() {
            daemon.init({
                lock: PID_FILE,
                stdin: '/dev/null',
                stdout: LOG_FILE,
                stderr: LOG_FILE,
                umask: 0,
                chroot: null,
                chdir: '.'
            });
        },
        stop = function() {
            process.kill(parseInt(require('fs').readFileSync(PID_FILE)));
        };

    switch(process.argv[2]) {
        case 'stop':
            stop();
            process.exit(0);
        break;

        case 'start':
            if(process.argv[3])
                process.env.EXPRESS_ENV = process.argv[3];
            start();
        break;

        case 'restart':
            stop();
            start();
            process.exit(0);
        break;

        case 'help':
            sys.puts('Usage: node app.js [start|stop|restart]');
            process.exit(0);
        break;
    }
} catch(e) {
    sys.puts('Daemon library not found! Please compile ' +
             './libs/daemon/daemon.node if you would like to use it.');
}
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/home/ec2-user/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/ec2-user/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/home/ec2-user/ca.pem'),
};

var app = express();

//app.set('env', 'development');
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(require('./middleware/im')({
   maxAge: 30 * 1000,
   reapInterval: 20 * 1000,
   authentication: require('./libs/authentication/' + AUTH_LIBRARY)
}));

app.set('root', __dirname);

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/dev/views');

    app.stack.unshift({
        route: '/dev',
        handle: function(req, res, next) {
            req.dev = true;
            next();
        }
    });

    app.use(express.logger());
    require('./dev/app')('/dev', app);
    app.use(express.static(
                require('path').join(__dirname, '../client')));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true}));
}

//app.listen(APP_PORT, APP_HOST);

// Listener endpoint; handled in middleware
app.get('/listen', function(){});

app.post('/message', function(req, res) {
    res.find(req.body['to'], function(user) {
        if(!user)
            return res.send(new packages.Error('not online'));

        res.message(user, new packages.Message(
            req.session.data('username'),
            req.body.body
        ));
    });
});

app.post('/message/typing', function(req, res) {
    if(~packages.TYPING_STATES.indexOf('typing' + req.body['state'])) {
        res.find(req.body['to'], function(user) {
            if(user) {
                res.message(user, new packages.Status(
                    req.session.data('username'),
                    'typing' + req.body.state
                ));
            }

            // Typing updates do not receive confirmations,
            // as they are not important enough.
            res.send('');
        });
    } else {
        res.send(new packages.Error('invalid state'));
    }
});

app.post('/status', function(req, res) {
    if(~packages.STATUSES.indexOf(req.body['status'])) {
        res.status(req.body.status, req.body.message);
        res.send(new packages.Success('status updated'));
    } else {
        res.send(new packages.Error('invalid status'));
    }
});


app.post('/online', function(req, res) {
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime() + 30;
req.sessionID.expires = n;
res.status(req.body.status, 'available');
});


app.post('/signoff', function(req, res) {
    res.signOff();
    res.send(new packages.Success('goodbye'));
});


app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, 'Error on the node/express server.');
});


https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you answer your question but I can try to point you in a right direction.

I'm currently working on a Node JS server myself, and I found very useful to have a logger setup.

There are a few of them, but my favorite is Winston so far.

Reference: https://github.com/flatiron/winston

To install Winston for your Node JS server (seems you have already installed a few modules):

```
npm install winston
```

Then I have **logger** module setup as (logger.js):

```
/**
 * Usage:
 *  - logger.info('sample text');
 *  - logger.warn('sample text');
 *  - logger.error('sample text');
 */

// Load modules
var winston = require('winston');

// Create custom logger
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/debug.log', json: false })
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', json: false })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});

// Export logger
module.exports = logger;
```

Finally I load in Winston logger module into my server scripts by:

```
var logger = require('./logger');
```

It will automatically log any exceptions into **exceptions.log** on your Node JS server location. It helped me out a lot to catch exceptions I haven't noticed before within Node JS unrelated to PHP.

P.S. Also check out socket.io, that may simplify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I use socket.io in another notification center. I have to solve this because even when i use socket.io, some users may still get to this problem since not all browsers support Websocket. And right now when this problem happens, the whole server is frozen and waiting for the response from node.js server forever, means no one can access any pages...thanks so much for the log tho.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed recently is that in certain cases of clients connecting and reconnecting as well as node js server restart there will be multiplication on connections. Basically the clients and the server will get multiple data on emitters. I fixed that by checking the duplicate message by timestamp. That was freezing up my server by a lot. If you keep track of connected clients in your node js server, check if any of them emit duplicate messages.